# Выделенный сервер у хостера. Хостер имеет доступ к данным?

Tags: сервер, хостинг, железо

Хостер устанавливает свой сервер, который я арендую, в стойку. И сам же устанавливает ОС Ubuntu. Естественно, при получении доступа, я меняю все root-пароли.

Как думаете, хостер имеет доступ к данным на диске? Может он для себя какую-то лазейку оставляет? Как можно заблокировать ему доступ к данным?

Так же имеется Консоль IPMI. У меня к ней доступа нет.

Во внимание не берем случай, когда хостер напрямую работает с сервером (лично подошел к серверу, отключил сервер, вытащил диск и т.д.). Т.е. пока сервер включен и работает.

Какие способы есть у хостера получить доступ к данным или управлять ОС? И можно ли им противостоять? :)

Строго не судите, я новичок в этом деле.

Comment: Можно оставить какой-нибудь аккаунт с id=0 (будем рутом). Можно где-то схоронить исполнимый бинарник (например, копию sh), принадлежащий руту с битом `s`. После этого из под рута можно запускать любые свои программы, смотреть память и диски.

Comment: Доброго! Во-первых, в сообществе это считается не этичным (иметь доступ к данным клиента); во-вторых, у хостера просто нет времени заниматься этой чушью. Теперь Вам: не храните такие данные на сервере, которые могут навредить Вам или Вашим пользователям; усильте логирование аутентификации и чаще мониторьте логи.